# SASS: keep CSS files separate in development and merge them in production

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I am using Grunt and SASS. I am currently using the [`grunt-contrib-compass`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) plugin.

My goal seemed simple, but it is very hard to achieve.

- During development I want my CSS to be compiled in separate files (because dev tools, speed of `watch` etc.)
- For production I want all of my CSS to be merged into one.

However using the `concat` task does not do the job.

When I have `@import` statements and SASS is compiling every file separately this outputs the same CSS from vendor libs like Bootstrap or Compass plugins over and over again in the different files. In development this is fine. When I `concat` the CSS files for production though it produces a quite bigger file with repetitive CSS.

How should I configure Grunt and use `@import` statements so this does not happen?

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer but an alternate solution.

For the use of dev tools I would recommend investigating .map files. This will allow you to have a compiled and minified css file but when you open the developer tools you can see the location of styles as they are in the original sass files.

- Details on the [grunt plugins GitHub page](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#sourcemap).
- A guide on [Sass and source maps](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools--net-32805).

I hope this helps.